# Trying to modify wordpress search submit button

Tags: css, wordpress

I know this is a simple thing, but I've tried everything (including googling and even hiring another programmer for an hour) and can't seem to make this work. The theme I'm working with has a specific color on the wordpress search box submit button, and I just need to change the color.

Looking at it with google development tools, the css looks like this:

```
.search-button, .submit_btn {
    background-color: #ffa025;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffa025 0%,#dc7214 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffa025 0%,#dc7214 100%);
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #f7b559 #e67e22 #e67e22 #e67e22;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 16%;
}
```

[screenshot of style from google dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsZkU.jpg)

What I'd like to do is just turn off the background-image attributes with the gradient and have the background color just be red. I've tried using the above selector, and then tried the selector: .search-button sBn, and put the code into the additional CSS field for theme. Nothing's working. Thanks for any help

Comment: `.search-button, .submit_btn {background: red;}` should work.

Answer (score 2):

As you have identified, the linear gradient set in background-image is overriding the background-color style. To reset the `background-image` to allow the background-color property be used instead, do the following:

```
background-image: none;
```

This will then reset the background colour to the `background-color` set in the theme css (i.e. #ffa025).

Now to change the color, you can set the `background-color` to whatever you want, e.g.

```
background-color: #ffa025;
```

You could also just use the `background` property, but that could have knock-on effects for other rules you have set up, so I'd suggest overriding the existing properties.

**Working snippet:**

```css
/* THEME CSS */
.search-button, .submit_btn {
    background-color: #ffa025;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffa025 0%,#dc7214 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffa025 0%,#dc7214 100%);
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #f7b559 #e67e22 #e67e22 #e67e22;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 16%;
}
/* YOUR CSS TO OVERRIDE THEME */
.search-button, .submit_btn {
    /* remove the gradient */
    background-image: none; 
    /* change the background colour to red */
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
```

Finally, don't forget to make sure that either your custom CSS is loaded after the theme CSS, or it uses a more specific selector than the theme CSS e.g.

```
.search-button.sBn {background-color: #ffa025;}
```

(*FYI, what you are trying to do is quite trivial so I'd be very concerned about the programmer you hired - this should have taken them no more than a couple of minutes*)